# SharedPreferences not saving values properly

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save a string to the shared preferences. The way I've tried to do this is the following:

```
ISharedPreferences _prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
ISharedPreferencesEditor _editor = _prefs.Edit();
_editor.PutString("myString", "123");
_editor.Commit();
```

Further down i try to print out my string:

```
_txtView.Text = _prefs.GetString("myString", "Can't find string");
```

When I run the application my textview now properly prints out "123". So everything is working as intended. However; the point of sharedpreferences is that it's persistent. So if I now try to comment out the following two lines:

```
_editor.PutString("myString", "123");
_editor.Commit();
```

Then build again, my textview displays "can't find string". So for some reason the string isn't being saved? Does anyone see why this is?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, you're using the synchronous method `Commit()` without checking the boolean return value (fail/success). Your should use the asynchronous method `Apply()` for a performance boost ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When building and deploying apps to your device, by default Xamarin will delete any existing application data/cache. This is not always ideal as it resets your data as if it were a fresh install.

To preserve data, you need to update the option:

- In Xamarin Studio, select Tools > Options > Projects > Android... Check "Preserve data/cache between application deploys"
- In Visual Studio, select Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings... Check "Preserve data/cache between application deploys"

Once you do this, any shared preferences or data files created in the local application folder will remain.

Answer (score 0):

*However, the point of sharedpreferences is that it's persistent* : It is persistent between **app executions**. When you comment out the code and launch again you are creating a *fresh* app, with no default stored preferences. That is why it is not working when you comment it out.

if you want it to store in shared preferences only once, then you should do a check whether the app is being executed for the *first time* or not, and then if *true*, store in shared preferences.

Comment: This was it. I've been developing some for Windows8 phone, where this works differently. The sharedpreferences there survives a complete rebuild (being stored in a system file, to my knowledge). Thank you for this.