# Xamarin Android losing keystore after each deploy in emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm discovering Xamarin Android with Visual Studio and I'm working with the keystore.

All my code is based on Xamarin's https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth

When I deploy and use the keystore, everything is working fine. Data are persisted and I can save, delete and retrieve them without a problem.

I can turn off the emulator or kill the application, the keystore is still here with the data in it.

But if I modify the code and redeploy the application without stopping the emulator, my keystore is lost.

Any idea on where I should start digging to troubleshoot this problem. I don't have any exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the setting to Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys.

Check this answer for details:

[SharedPreferences not saving values properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825872/sharedpreferences-not-saving-values-properly/21834310#21834310)